# Action function always returning same reducer type in React after calling backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-reducers

So I'm in the last step to finish my 2FA methods, right now in  the one in which I need to detect wether a user has enabled his or not and to achieve that, I created a funtion which returns the following:

```
if (!user.twoFactorTokenEnabled) {
  // If user has not enabled twoFactorAuthentication, then
  // let him proceed and log in into his account
  sendTokenResponse(user, 200, req, res)
} else {
  // Otherwise, just return the following fields:
  // username, isEmailConfirmed and twoFactorTokenEnabled
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: user })
}
```

That function is located in the backend and so far it works well or at least that's  what I want to believe.
Now with that being said, I get into my login component and trigger the `login` function everytime I submit the form:

```
const [TFAEEnabled, setTFAEnabled] = useState(false)

login(loginData, history)
  .then((result) => {
    // If twoFactorTokenEnabled is found to be true
    // then call this function and set it to true and then
    // display and extra field to enter
    // a google authenticator code
    setTFAEnabled(result.payload.data.twoFactorTokenEnabled)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    setTFAEnabled(false)
    setError(true)
  })

// This is found within my returned component.
{
  TFAEEnabled && (
    <Form.Control
      type="text"
      placeholder="Authenticator Code"
      aria-label="2FA-CODE"
      aria-describedby="2FA-CODE-text"
      autoComplete="2FA-CODE"
      name="2FA-CODE"
      id="2FA-CODE"
      minLength="6"
      required
      // onChange={handleChange('2FA-CODE')}
      value="2FA Code"
    />
  )
}
```

In the code above and tried to show what it is that I'm trying to accomplish which is "just show this component if X is true". However the function is not totally working at all since it always ends up calling the first reducer type, this is the login function:

```
export const login = (loginData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.post(`/auth/login`, loginData)

    if (!res.data.twoFactorTokenEnabled) {
      // if twoFactorTokenEnabled === false then let
      // the user log in into his account normally
      // without requiring a token provided by Y
      // authenticator app
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      })
      // Dispatch the rest of the user data
      dispatch(loadUser())
      //  and let him in
      history.push('/timeline')
    } else {
      // otherwise, if twoFactorTokenEnabled === true
      // return the previously mentioned data given by
      // the backend: username, isEmailConfirmed and
      // twoFactorTokenEnabled
      return dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS_REQUEST,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    }
  } catch (err) {
    const error = err.response.data.message
    const errors = err?.response?.data?.errors

    if (error) {
      dispatch(setAlert(error, 'danger'))
    }

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')))
    }
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload: { msg: err.response?.statusText, status: err.response?.status },
    })
  }
}
```

The backend works great!, it returns the data that its supposed to return, the problem I believe resides in my reducer which is this:

```
// if twoFactorTokenEnabled === true
// call this reducer which should only return
// the 4 fields given by the backend
case LOGIN_SUCCESS_REQUEST:
  return {
    ...state,
    // ...payload,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isTFAEnabled: payload,
    loading: false
  };
// Otherwise let the user in and return everything
case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      ...payload,
      isAuthenticated: true,
      loading: false
    };
```

Hopefully this could be enough to explain, otherwise feel free to request more info.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out that I was not returning the data according to what the backend was sending, I had to return a second 'data' in the if-statement:

```
const res = await api.post(`/auth/login`, loginData);

    if (res.data.data) {
      history.push(`/two-fa-validate/${res.data.data._id}`);
      return dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS_REQUEST,
        payload: res.data
      });
    }
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });
    dispatch(loadUser());
    history.push('/timeline');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Redux-thunk and you need to dispatch your action function.
And then TFAEEnabled can be selected from the Redux store.

```
const TFAEEnabled = useSelector(state => state.isAuthenticated);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

dispatch(login(loginData, history));
```